# Как доступиться к Border базовго класа, а именно к его свойству "Background"?

Tags: c#, wpf, style

Из дочернего стиля доступиться к сэттеру(Border) базового и добавить свойство Background и изменить его в дочернем стиле. На словах тяжело объяснить, поэтому даю скрин, заранее извиняюсь за столь глухое описание проблемы([image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там TargetType="{x:Type Button}", а не TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" *

Comment: А что вам мешает в базовом стиле задать нужный цвет (`<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>`, `<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ...`) и уже его переопределять в наследнике, без использования имен?

Comment: И это что либо меняет? Зачем вам тут вообще `x:Name`?

Comment: Спасибо, все работает